# How can I test Restkit object serialization / upload?

Tags: restkit

I've figured out how to test the download mapping for objects, but I'm at an utter loss to test the inverse -- that objects properly serialize back into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `RKMappingTest` in just the same way for both serialisation and deserialisation. Supply a request mapping instead of a response mapping. The source object will be one of your model classes. The destination object will be a mutable dictionary. Expectations are set in the same way.